# performing mergeSort on LinkedLists

Tags: c++, linked-list, quicksort, mergesort

I was assigned to code a project which to some extend simulates timetable of an airport. This has to be implemented using linkedLists. The poject should consist of Node class and SLL (singly linked list) class. The logic of the project is like this: There should be a clock which ticks every 15 minutes in the main function; I created flight.h file and included all the information related to a flight within. What confuses me here is just some parts of the code related to mergeSort and quickSort.
The project asks to sort all the flights: 1. based on their departure time 2. bases on their departure city.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

#ifndef FLIGHT_H_
#define FLIGHT_H_

class Node
{
public:
    Node()
    {
        flightNum = 0;
        gate = 0;
        status = On_time;
        next = NULL;
    }
    enum Flight_status {On_time, Delayed, Departed};
    struct Time {int hour, minutes;}; time;
    string airLine;
    int flightNum;
    string city;
    int gate;
    Flight_status status;
    Node *next;
    friend class SLL;
};

class SLL
{
private:
    Node *head;
    Node *tail;
    int size;
public:
    SLL() {head = tail = NULL; size = 0;}
    ~SLL() {};
    // Member function to add a new Node into a list
    void addNode();
    // Member functions to perform mergeSort over the list
    void split(SLL *, int, int);
    void merge(SLL *, int, int, int);
    // Member functions to perform quickSort over the list
    void partition(SLL *, int, int);
    void swap(Node &, Node &);
    void quickSort(SLL *, int, int);
    //
    void display(SLL *);
};

#endif /* FLIGHT_H_ */
```

I'm thinking about building the rest of the program on top of this declaration. what I want to make sure about is my approach to solve the sorting problem is good according to this implementation of classes. Please help me if you find any problem implementing this project.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't really see a question in there. What do you have problems with? The implementation of the sorting? Just a review of the classes? Something else?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg- Yeah the problem that really confuses me is the implementation and linkage of the results of the functions, I did work on the Flight.h file but writing the exact functions, their returns and how should they be connected together is really confusing. Would you help me with that?

Comment: Its a  linked list. Whats the confusing part? I mean *besides* taking what look like non-class function prototypes and hanging them in the SLL class. If you're going that route I would suggest they be static and private (and honestly, I would suggest using `std::vector<>` and `std::sort`, but am fairly confident  the TA grading this exercise would not share that opinion).

Comment: I guess what @JoachimPileborg is poking on is that "Here's a bunch a stuff.  I want to do X.  Please help me," isn't really a question.  It is a request.  Shouldn't the focus be "I'm trying to do X, and I got this far, but I've hit this specific stumbling point.  What should I do to get past stumbling point Y?  I've tried A, B and C, but got these errors..."  Much more focused.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code.. Modify it according to your problem.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

/* Link list node */
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
};

/* function prototypes */
struct node* SortedMerge(struct node* a, struct node* b);
void FrontBackSplit(struct node* source,
          struct node** frontRef, struct node** backRef);

/* sorts the linked list by changing next pointers (not data) */
void MergeSort(struct node** headRef)
{
  struct node* head = *headRef;
  struct node* a;
  struct node* b;

  /* Base case -- length 0 or 1 */
  if ((head == NULL) || (head->next == NULL))
  {
    return;
  }

  /* Split head into 'a' and 'b' sublists */
  FrontBackSplit(head, &a, &b); 

  /* Recursively sort the sublists */
  MergeSort(&a);
  MergeSort(&b);

  /* answer = merge the two sorted lists together */
  *headRef = SortedMerge(a, b);
}

struct node* SortedMerge(struct node* a, struct node* b)
{
  struct node* result = NULL;

  /* Base cases */
  if (a == NULL)
     return(b);
  else if (b==NULL)
     return(a);

  /* Pick either a or b, and recur */
  if (a->data <= b->data)
  {
     result = a;
     result->next = SortedMerge(a->next, b);
  }
  else
  {
     result = b;
     result->next = SortedMerge(a, b->next);
  }
  return(result);
}

/* UTILITY FUNCTIONS */
/* Split the nodes of the given list into front and back halves,
     and return the two lists using the reference parameters.
     If the length is odd, the extra node should go in the front list.
     Uses the fast/slow pointer strategy.  */
void FrontBackSplit(struct node* source,
          struct node** frontRef, struct node** backRef)
{
  struct node* fast;
  struct node* slow;
  if (source==NULL || source->next==NULL)
  {
    /* length < 2 cases */
    *frontRef = source;
    *backRef = NULL;
  }
  else
  {
    slow = source;
    fast = source->next;

    /* Advance 'fast' two nodes, and advance 'slow' one node */
    while (fast != NULL)
    {
      fast = fast->next;
      if (fast != NULL)
      {
        slow = slow->next;
        fast = fast->next;
      }
    }

    /* 'slow' is before the midpoint in the list, so split it in two
      at that point. */
    *frontRef = source;
    *backRef = slow->next;
    slow->next = NULL;
  }
}

/* Function to print nodes in a given linked list */
void printList(struct node *node)
{
  while(node!=NULL)
  {
   printf("%d ", node->data);
   node = node->next;
  }
}

/* Function to insert a node at the beginging of the linked list */
void push(struct node** head_ref, int new_data)
{
  /* allocate node */
  struct node* new_node =
            (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));

  /* put in the data  */
  new_node->data  = new_data;

  /* link the old list off the new node */
  new_node->next = (*head_ref);    

  /* move the head to point to the new node */
  (*head_ref)    = new_node;
} 

/* Drier program to test above functions*/
int main()
{
  /* Start with the empty list */
  struct node* res = NULL;
  struct node* a = NULL;

  /* Let us create a unsorted linked lists to test the functions
   Created lists shall be a: 2->3->20->5->10->15 */
  push(&a, 15);
  push(&a, 10);
  push(&a, 5); 
  push(&a, 20);
  push(&a, 3);
  push(&a, 2); 

  /* Sort the above created Linked List */
  MergeSort(&a);

  printf("\n Sorted Linked List is: \n");
  printList(a);           

  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

Sources : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort
http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/105/LinkedListProblems.pdf
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort-for-linked-list/